# Is it possible to launch a process to handle an incoming TCP connection?

Tags: linux, nginx, tcp, proxy, haproxy

Is there a way to accept a TCP connection via a TCP proxy (nginx, haproxy or maybe the Linux kernel with iptables), boot a process on a remote host in response, and then forward the connection to that process? Alternatively, is it possible to script nginx or haproxy to run a script when the TCP connection is received, and "hold" or "pause" the TCP connection until a backend server is available to handle the connection from the proxy?

Comment: This is exactly what `inetd` already does.

Comment: @user207421 sorry, I should have clarified: what if the receiving process runs on a different host from the proxy?

Comment: Then you would need remote launch capability; you would need to know about the port it uses, if it's a server, or tell it the port to connect to if it's a client, ... lots of details but nothing inherently impossible.

Comment: It is also possible to 'holr or pause' the incoming connection, simply by doing nothing with it, but the peer is liable to incur read timeouts.

Comment: @user207421 Yep, understood. Hold or pause was in the context of haproxy/nginx, which will close the connection to the client if the backend service is not already accepting connections.

Comment: @MattFichman why is it not possible to run the process alway on the remote server like a daemon? This could be a possible solution https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Fastrouter.html#cheap-mode-and-shared-sockets